# Android : getParcelableArrayList error (out of Memory)

Tags: android

I have a question about parcelable class (android).

Until now, I have passed a DoubleArray between 2 Intent whithout any problem:

```
new double[] latLong = new double[]{loc.getLatitude(),loc.getLongitude()};
...
intent.putExtra(Site.LATTITUDE, latLong);   
...
startActivityForResult(intent, this.ACCESS_GOOGLE);
```

Today, I tried to add new data for the same activities using parcelable class. 
My parcelable class:

```
package common;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Site implements Parcelable {

    private int id;
    private String site_name;
    private int category ;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    /**
     * 
     * @param id
     * @param site_name
     * @param category
     */
    public Site(int id, String site_name, int category,double latitude, double lonngitude){
        this.id=id;
        this.site_name=site_name;
        this.category=category;
        this.latitude=latitude;
        this.longitude=longitude;

    }

    public Site(Parcel in){
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(this.id);
        dest.writeString(this.site_name);
        dest.writeInt(this.category);
        dest.writeDouble(this.latitude);
        dest.writeDouble(this.longitude);
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @param in
     */
    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {        
        this.id     = in.readInt();
        this.site_name  = in.readString();
        this.category   = in.readInt();
        this.latitude   = in.readInt();
        this.longitude  = in.readInt();
    }


   public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR =
        new Parcelable.Creator() {

            public SiteGoogle createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Site(in);
            }

            public SiteGoogle[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Site[size];
            }
        };


    /* GETTER / SETTER */

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSite_name() {
        return site_name;
    }

    public void setSite_name(String site_name) {
        this.site_name = site_name;
    }

    public int getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(int category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

}
```

I put some Site objects(above class) in a java ArrayList, and pass this list to my second Activity with the below code :

```
ArrayList<Site> sitesForMap = new ArrayList<Site>();

for(int i=0; i<sites.size();i++){

    SiteGoogle site = new SiteGoogle(
            sites.get(i).getId(),
            sites.get(i).getSite_name(),
            sites.get(i).getCat(),
            sites.get(i).getLatitude(),
            sites.get(i).getLongitude());

    sitesForGoogle.add(site); 
}

//put data in the intent
intent.putExtra(Site.LATTITUDE, latLong); //first data that worked well until now
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Site.JSON_ARRAY, sitesForMap);   //my new data
startActivityForResult(intent, this.ACCESS_GOOGLE);
```

This code is executed perfectly(sitesForMap and latLong are not null) but in the second Activity, when I try to instance the first Double[] parameter,
an error occured .

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
double[] adresse = (double[]) bundle.getDoubleArray(Site.LATTITUDE);    //worked well until today
List<Site> sitesList = bundle.getParcelableArrayList(Site.JSON_ARRAY);
```

Error :

```
11-04 03:00:47.248: D/AndroidRuntime(642): Shutting down VM
11-04 03:00:47.248: W/dalvikvm(642): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Parcel.readArray(Parcel.java:1476)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1810)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2017)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1461)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1792)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2008)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:208)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Bundle.getDoubleArray(Bundle.java:1431)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at alij.ne.jp.GoogleMapActivity.onCreate(GoogleMapActivity.java:111)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-04 03:00:47.350: E/AndroidRuntime(642):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-04 03:03:10.460: I/Process(642): Sending signal. PID: 642 SIG: 9
11-04 03:03:11.099: D/dalvikvm(652): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 792 objects / 61464 bytes in 48ms
```

Someone knows what is the problem ?

Thank you for reading my message !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your readFromParcel and writeToParcel methods doesn't match.

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(this.id);
    dest.writeString(this.site_name);
    dest.writeInt(this.category);
    dest.writeDouble(this.latitude);
    dest.writeDouble(this.longitude);
}

private void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {        
    this.id     = in.readInt();
    this.site_name  = in.readString();
    this.category   = in.readInt();
    this.latitude   = in.readInt(); // <-------- this
    this.longitude  = in.readInt(); // <-------- and this
}
```

A double uses 8 bytes, and an int uses 4 bytes on the parcel. A parcel doesn't contain type information (except if you use writeValue and readValue), so if you mismatch the read and write methods, an unexpected value will be read and it will mess the whole parcel.

If you really want an int, use (int) in.readDouble() instead of in.readInt().

Comment: you saved my life Yuku ! Thank you for your quick answer. I change the "readint" to "readDouble" and now it work well.

Comment: thanks yuku for pointing this place out, in my case, I forgot to add line to writeToParcel()...